# How to conditionally change another field in another component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have Form component.

```
class Form extends Component {
   render() {
       
        const fields = [
            {
                id: 'first-name',
                name: 'first_name',
                label: 'First Name,
                type: text,
                defaultValue: 'Nick',
                isShowing: true
            },
            {
                id: 'city',
                name: 'city',
                label: 'City',
                type: 'select',
                defaultValue: 'mithriya',
                options: [
                    {
                        value: 'georgina',
                        label: 'Georgina'
                    },

                    {
                        value: 'mithriya',
                        label: 'Mithriya'
                    }
                ],
                isShowing: false
            },
        ];

        return (
        <div className="pkg-settings">
            <form method="post">
                <table className="form-table">
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            fields.map( (field) =>

                                <Field key={field.id} attr={field} />
                            )
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <p className="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" className="button button-primary button-large" value="Save Changes" /></p>

            </form>
        </div>
    )
```

The form fields are different components individually:

```
class Field extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: props.attr.defaultValue,
            isShowing: props.attr.isShowing
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState(
            {
                value: event.target.value
            }
        );

        if ( 'city' === event.target.name && 'georgina' === event.target.value) {
               // I'd need to change First Name's isShowing. City's isShowing can be changed by using: this.setState.
        }
    }

   render() {

       var element = '';

        switch(this.props.attr.type) {
            case 'text':
                element = <input
                            type="text"
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            name='first_name'
                            value={this.state.value}
                        />;
            break;

case 'select':
                element = <select
                            name='city'
                            value={this.state.value}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}>

                            {
                                this.props.attr.options.map( (option) =>
                                    <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                                )
                            }

                            </select>
            break;
   
       return (
               this.state.isShowing
                ?
                 <tr valign="top">
                        <th scope="row">{this.props.attr.label}</th>
                        <td>
                             {element}
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                :

                null
                
           );
    }
```

With this, I can change isShowing of the field that I'm currently changing, but I'd want to change isShowing of the another field depending on the value of current field.

`this` is always about the current field. Or am I doing it the wrong way? Should all the fields be in the same class?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: All the answers here that point out the fact that the state needs to move up (to the `Form` instead of individual `Field`) are 100% correct. In addition, your logic for showing or not showing a field can be a derived state (derived from `Form` component's state). If you resonate with this idea, I can share a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since one field affects the state of another field, then one way would be to move the state for `isShowing` to the parent component(`Form` component). The state for `isShowing` in the parent component would be an array of boolean values storing the value for each of the fields. You could have a callback defined to update the state for `isShowing` in the `Form` component which could be passed to `Field` component.

```
class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    isShowing: []
  }

  updateIsShowingForField = (index, value) => {
    const isShowingClone = [...this.state.isShowing];
    isShowingClone[index] = value;

    this.setState({
      isShowing: isShowingClone
    });
  }

  render() {
    return fields.map(field, index => <Field
           key={field.id}
           attr={field}
           isShowing={this.state.isShowing[index]}
           updateIsShowingForField={this.updateIsShowingForField}
    />)
  }
}
```

Comment: @micky I have edited my answer to show an example

Comment: @vikram-patel thanks for the example. However, I'm still not able to figure that out. Nothing is updating with that. Can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

Since in the implementation, fields are going to be children nodes that don't have access to each other. Children need a common source of knowledge where they can maintain data.

A common source of truth can be a redux store or react context if things are on a larger level. However, in the above scenario, we can take the state of the parent component as the source of truth.

Now here is my implementation using functional components along with some optimization and code improvements:

Here comes the Form.jsx implementation:

```
// Form.jsx

// Defining fields outside the component in order to avoid the declaration 
// and assigning of variable on each render
const FIELDS = [
    {
        id: 'first-name',
        name: 'first_name',
        label: 'First Name',
        type: 'text',
        defaultValue: 'Nick',
        isVisible: true
    },
    {
        id: 'city',
        name: 'city',
        label: 'City',
        type: 'select',
        defaultValue: 'mithriya',
        options: [
            {
                value: 'georgina',
                label: 'Georgina'
            },

            {
                value: 'mithriya',
                label: 'Mithriya'
            }
        ],
        isVisible: true
    },
];

const Form = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState(FIELDS);

  const onFieldChange = (index, value) => {
    const fieldToUpdate = fields[index];
    fieldToUpdate.value = value;

    let otherFields = fields.splice(index, 1);

    // condition to update other fields
    if (fieldToUpdate.name === "city" && value === "georgina") {
      const conditionalFieldToUpdateIndex = otherFields.findIndex(
        (field) => field.name === "first_name",
      );
      const conditionalField = otherFields[conditionalFieldToUpdateIndex];
      conditionalField.isVisible = false;
      const leftOutFields = otherFields.splice(conditionalFieldToUpdateIndex, 1);
      otherFields = [...leftOutFields, { ...conditionalField }];
    }

    const fieldsToUpdate = [...otherFields, { ...fieldToUpdate }];
    setFields(fieldsToUpdate);
  };

  return (
    <div className="pkg-settings">
      <form method="post">
        <table className="form-table">
          <tbody>
            {fields.map((field, index) => (
              <Field
                key={field.id}
                field={field}
                onChange={(value) => onFieldChange(index, value)}
              />
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <p className="submit">
          <input
            type="submit"
            name="submit"
            id="submit"
            className="button button-primary button-large"
            value="Save Changes"
          />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Field Change is being handled inside the form which makes things easier and also easy to manage. Here comes the Field.jsx implementation:

```
const Field = (props) => {
  const {
    field,
    field: { name, value, type, defaultValue, isVisible },
    onChange,
  } = props;

  if (!isVisible) {
    return <React.Fragment />;
  }

  let elementToRender;

  switch (type) {
    case "select":
      elementToRender = (
        <select
          name={name}
          value={value}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
        >
          {field.options.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      );
      break;

    default:
      elementToRender = (
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
          name={name}
          value={value}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
        />
      );

      return elementToRender;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I really think the way you're doing the form over-complicated it it's just a form, forms are supposed to have different inputs so yeah having all the fields in the same class would really make you suffer less ... if you insist on this way then what the first comment suggested is the way to go to have a state in the Form component and have the  updateIsShowingForField in the Form as well, pass it as a prop to all components and invoke it in each input field which when invoked in the child component will return the value to the parent component ...

If you are confused on how to pass data from child to parent take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@jasminegump/passing-data-between-a-parent-and-child-in-react-deea2ec8e654)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a updateProps method from parent to child as below

**Parent.jsx code**

```
// code to update props
updateChildProps(childProps){
   this.setState({...state, childProps});
}
// render calling Child
render() {
  return <Child {...childProps , updateProps: updateChildProps} />
}
```

**Child.jsx code**

```
// on input change
if(condition met){
    const newProps = {...this.props};
    newProps["fieldToChange"] = valueToChange;
    this.props.updateProps(newProps);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to break it down into smaller steps in order to solve your question.

1. We'll hold the value of the `fields` array in a state of `Form.js` component. So, whenever we update the fields state, it will cause a re-render of the application. ( In your case we will update the isShowing property of some fields based on your condition ).

```
 this.state = {
      fields: [
        {
          id: "first-name",
          name: "first_name",
          label: "First Name",
          type: "text",
          defaultValue: "Nick",
          isShowing: false
        },
        {
          id: "city",
          name: "city",
          label: "City",
          type: "select",
          defaultValue: "georgina",
          options: [
            {
              value: "georgina",
              label: "Georgina"
            },

            {
              value: "mithriya",
              label: "Mithriya"
            }
          ],
          isShowing: true
        }
      ]
    };
```

2. We'll add a handler in our `Form` component say `handleFieldsChange` for handling the visibility of the `first_name` input field based on the Combobox input value. This handler will accept two arguments one is the `name` of the input box and `value` of the input box. This handler will be called when there is a change in the input field.

```
 // Form.js
 handleFieldsChange(name, value) {
    if (name === "city" && value === "mithriya") {
      this.setState({
        fields: this.state.fields.map((field) =>
          field.id === "first-name" ? { ...field, isShowing: true } : field
        )
      });
    }
  }

 // Field.js
 handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });

    // here we call the handleFieldsChange handler
    this.props.handleFieldsChange(event.target.name, event.target.value); 
 }
```

3. Remove `isShowing` local state from the fields component as we are updating this state from the `Form` component itself. So, there is no need to have one more local state in the Fields component.

So, if we follow all these steps we could solve your question. I have a codesandbox link where I simulate your case and the **good part** is everything is working as you wanted to have.

[image: Edit Type e.target]

I will also paste the code here so we don't have to move to another page.

**Form.js**:

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: [
        {
          id: "first-name",
          name: "first_name",
          label: "First Name",
          type: "text",
          defaultValue: "Nick",
          isShowing: false
        },
        {
          id: "city",
          name: "city",
          label: "City",
          type: "select",
          defaultValue: "georgina",
          options: [
            {
              value: "georgina",
              label: "Georgina"
            },

            {
              value: "mithriya",
              label: "Mithriya"
            }
          ],
          isShowing: true
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleFieldsChange = this.handleFieldsChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleFieldsChange(name, value) {
    if (name === "city" && value === "mithriya") {
      this.setState({
        fields: this.state.fields.map((field) =>
          field.id === "first-name" ? { ...field, isShowing: true } : field
        )
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.fields);
    return (
      <div className="pkg-settings">
        <form method="post">
          <table className="form-table">
            <tbody>
              {this.state.fields.map((field) => (
                <Field
                  key={field.id}
                  attr={field}
                  handleFieldsChange={this.handleFieldsChange}
                />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <p className="submit">
            <input
              type="submit"
              name="submit"
              id="submit"
              className="button button-primary button-large"
              value="Save Changes"
            />
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Field.js**:

```
export default class Field extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.attr.defaultValue
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });

    this.props.handleFieldsChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    var element = "";

    switch (this.props.attr.type) {
      case "text":
        element = (
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name="first_name"
            value={this.state.value}
          />
        );
        break;

      case "select":
        element = (
          <select
            name="city"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          >
            {this.props.attr.options.map((option) => (
              <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        );
        break;
      default:
        element = <></>;
    }
    return this.props.attr.isShowing ? (
      <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">{this.props.attr.label}</th>
        <td>{element}</td>
      </tr>
    ) : null;
  }
}
```